# Display name from an Inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I've been following a udemy course about object oriented php and wanted to improve the final result of the project.

We've create a shareboard where we display the shares of every user who posts one and I wanted to add in the shares page the user who posts the share.

Theres is two tables so far in the db one for the shares with a user_id to link with the user in the users table

Here's the current code:

The model:

```
class ShareModel extends Model{
    public function Index(){
       $this->query('SELECT * FROM shares ORDER BY create_date DESC');
       $rows = $this->resultSet();
       return $rows;
    }
}
```

The view:

```
<div>
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) : ?>
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-share" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>shares/add">Share Something</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php foreach($viewmodel as $item) : ?>
        <div class="well">
            <h3><?php echo $item['title']; ?></h3>
            <small><?php echo $item['create_date']; ?></small>
            <hr />
            <p><?php echo $item['body']; ?></p>
            <small><?php echo $item['user_id']; ?></small>
            <br /><br />
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo $item['link']; ?>" target="_blank">Go To Website</a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

I know in the model I need to change the index like this:

```
class ShareModel extends Model{
    public function Index(){
        $query1 = $this->query('SELECT * FROM shares ORDER BY create_date DESC');
        $query2 = $this->query('SELECT shares.id, users.name FROM shares INNER JOIN Users ON shares.user_id = users.id');

        return array($query1, $query2);
    }
}
```

But how can I access this in the view to display the content of the sahre and the name of the user?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, in view file,print_r() the `$viewmodel`. `$viewmodel[0]`  will return the result set of 1st query & `$viewmodel[1]` will return the resultset of 2nd.

Also why you want to write the 2 queries?
Write single one like :

```
SELECT shares.id,shares.*, users.name 
FROM shares 
INNER JOIN Users ON shares.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

Comment: No need for `shares.id`, since that will be in `shares.*`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `$this->resultSet()` after each query.

```
public function Index(){
    $query1 = $this->query('SELECT * FROM shares ORDER BY create_date DESC');
    $result1 = $this->resultSet();
    $query2 = $this->query('SELECT shares.id, users.name FROM shares INNER JOIN Users ON shares.user_id = users.id');
    $result2 = $this->resultSet();

    return array($result1, $result2);
}
```